# AppSync: manage failed functions in pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-appsync, aws-step-functions

I am writing an AppSync application and I have a problem with a pipeline of resolvers. The actual pipeline has a first lambda function that creates a record in Salesforce and then inserts a record in a RDS (Aurora Serverless).

If Aurora Serverless DB cluster after a given amount of time with no activity is pausing, the connection is lost and this shutdown breaks the pipeline creating inconsistent data between the two source data.

But it isn't the problem because I can add a lambda function between the two state to pre warm RDS Cluster, but I want to try handling errors from this function and retry if necessary, or add the item in SQS.

How can I do it in AppSync?
Can I handle this with a StepFunctions? (see [here](https://d1.awsstatic.com/events/reinvent/2019/REPEAT_2_AWS_AppSync_does_that_Support_for_alternative_data_sources_MOB318-R2.pdf))